# Python: Attempting to append to file but nothing is being written

Tags: python, python-3.x

This section of code should write an input and another variable (Score) to a text file. The program asks for the input (so the if statement is definitely working) and runs without errors, but the text file is empty. Oddly, copying this code to an empty python file and running it works without errors. What is happening here?

```
if Score > int(HighScores[1]):
    print("You beat the record with " + str(Score) + " points!")
    Name = input("What is your name?")
    BestOf = open("High Scores.txt", "w").close()
    BestOf = open("High Scores.txt", "a")
    BestOf.write(Name + "\n")
    BestOf.write(str(Score))
```

Comment: Are you sure you're closing the file after appending?

Comment: Also, you realize `BestOf = open("High Scores.txt", "w").close()` simply truncates the file, essentially deleting any contents already there? It therefore makes no sense, and you could just work with `open(..., 'w')` the entire time, since there is *nothing left to append to*.

Comment: Idk if you need to write first for this to happen, but I'd think `open("High Scores.txt", "w")` would overwrite the previous contents since you're not opening it in append mode.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you don't need to write. `open(<something>, 'w')` truncates first.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the confirmation. Well, there you go. I hedged since he says it works in some contexts.

Comment: Thanks @HeshamAttia you were right, I didn't close the file. Thanks juanpa.arrivillaga I thought that any time using .write in write mode clears the file, not just when you first open. I'm very new with python and I've kind of being making things up as I've gone along haha. The code works now that I've added the .close() Anyone know how I can mark this as solved?

Comment: But what were you trying to accomplish with `BestOf = open("High Scores.txt", "w").close()` ?

Comment: Clearing the file. I wanted it to only store the highest score because I'm too lazy to make a file that sorts multiple scores from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't close the file after appending.

```
BestOf.close()
```

fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in 'w+' mode. This will create the file if it doesn't exist.
You can also check if the file exits using the 'os' module.

```
import os;
if Score > int(HighScores[1]):
    print("You beat the record with " + str(Score) + " points!")
    name = input("What is your name?")
    if os.path.isfile("Scores.txt"):
        fh = open("Scores.txt", "a")
    else:
        fh = open("Scores.txt", "w+")
    fh.write(name + "\n")
    fh.write(str(Score))
    fh.close()
```